# Google map in laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1 framework, with the startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6.

i separate this JavaScript to **app.blade.php** (which is inside the folder **master**)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;        
                        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myCenter
            });

            function initialize() {
              var mapProp = {
                  center:myCenter,
                  zoom: 14,
                  draggable: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

              map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
              marker.setMap(map);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);

              }); 
            };
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());

            $('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
               //Must wait until the render of the modal appear, thats why we use the resizeMap and NOT resizingMap!! ;-)
               resizeMap();
            })

            function resizeMap() {
               if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
               setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
            }

            function resizingMap() {
               if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
               var center = map.getCenter();
               google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
               map.setCenter(center); 
            }

            </script>


<body>

@yield('content')


</body>
```

And here is my **index.blade.php** (which is inside the folder **pages**)

```
@extends('content.app')
@section('content')


<h1 class="">Google Map</h1> 
<a href="#myMapModal" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Map Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

@endsection
```

I couldn't get it why it's not functioning. T__T...Any help guys?

Comment: "it's not functioning" - can you be more specific? Are you getting an error, is the map not appearing?

Comment: @duncan no sir i didn't get any error but the map didn't appear... ^^

Comment: Are you including the Google Maps script?  e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: and what does your relevant CSS look like?